# Starting intent from xml

Tags: android, xml, android-intent, android-preferences

I'm trying to have my preferences have an option to go to the system wi-fi settings.

```
<PreferenceScreen
    android:title="Wifi">
    <intent android:action="android.settings.MAIN"/>
</PreferenceScreen>
```

This pops up a menu where I can select a bunch of activities, wi-fi settings being one of them. Using logcat, I was able to see

```
act=android.intent.action.MAIN 
cmp=com.android.settings/.wifi.WifiSettings
```

How can I call this? The android documentation isn't very clear. I found ACTION_WIFI_SETTINGS in the reference, but I can't figure out how to call it directly from the intent.

Thanks

Edit: I tried android:component, but apparently that doesn't exist

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try using `ACTION_PICK_WIFI_NETWORK` to directly access Wi-Fi settings:

```
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >    
    <Preference 
        android:key="key"   
        android:title="WiFi" 
        android:summary="Calls WiFi">           
            <intent android:action="android.net.wifi.PICK_WIFI_NETWORK"/>           
    </Preference>
</PreferenceScreen>
```

**P.S.**

The component is composed of two parts: `android:targetPackage` and `android:targetClass`. If you want to know what other xml attributes `Intent` accepts, then go here: [attrs_manifext.xml](http://codesearch.google.com/codesearch#uX1GffpyOZk/core/res/res/values/attrs_manifest.xml&type=cs&l=1463)

```
    <!-- The package part of the ComponentName to assign to the Intent, as per
        {@link android.content.Intent#setComponent Intent.setComponent()}. -->
    <attr name="targetPackage" />

    <!-- The class part of the ComponentName to assign to the Intent, as per
        {@link android.content.Intent#setComponent Intent.setComponent()}. -->
    <attr name="targetClass" format="string" />
```

Comment: How did you go about figuring out what the action should be? The android documentation doesn't really have a clear guide to figuring it out. For instance, what is ACTION_WIFI_SETTINGS for?

Comment: Yes, it has. See: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.html#ACTION_PICK_WIFI_NETWORK, note the **Constant value** field.

Comment: Same for `ACTION_WIFI_SETTING`, see http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.html#ACTION_WIFI_SETTINGS. The value is `android.settings.WIFI_SETTINGS`. By the way both `ACTION_WIFI_SETTINGS` and `ACTION_PICK_WIFI_NETWORK` are equivalent. This is not well-documented, but you'll see yourself (this also can be seen from android source code).

Comment: :-/ android.settings.WIFI_SETTINGS was the first thing I tried, but I had an extra space at the end. Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 2):

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.android.settings", "com.android.settings.wifi.WifiSettings"));
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: That would be to launch the intent from code. I'm trying to do it from XML.